# How to parse rss feed on client side in React

Tags: reactjs, rss

I am trying to parse rss feed in my React application (in componentDidMount). I've looked at multiple js libraries that do this but they all work on the server side. Does anyone know npm packages that work on the client side? Or is it easier for me to write my own function that does the parsing?

Answer (score 3):

Using 'rss-parser' as mentioned, this worked for me:

```
let parser = new Parser();
const CORS_PROXY = "<some cors proxy>";

(async () => {
  let feed = await parser.parseURL(CORS_PROXY + this.props.url);
  feed.items.forEach(item => {
    console.log(item);
  });
})();
```

[npm rss-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rss-parser)

Answer (score 2):

Check out [rss-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rss-parser).
From the readme, you can use it to parse rss from three locations

> parseString(xml, [options,], callback)
>   parseFile(filename, [options,], callback) (This one isn't client sided, so not for you).
>   parseURL(url, [options,] callback)

Comment: Thanks but it says in the description that it is Node.js only like most of other packages I've tried.

Comment: That's only for the `parseFile` function. How are you getting the feed data in your app?

Comment: I am using fetch. So you mean that I could use parseFile after fetching?

Comment: You can either use `parseString('fetch result string', callbackFunc)`
or can skip using fetch with `parseURL('urlToFeed', callbackFunc)`